# How to use Web browser object to display a pdf file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying do display a pdf file on a form which contains a Web browser. I have previously used the below code which sometimes works but now I am constantly getting an error at line `webBrowser2.Navigate pdfFilePath`. The pdf file exists in the path and is named correctly. Please see the rest of code and help if you can:

```
Sub loadPDFFile()
Dim webBrowser2 As WebBrowser
Dim pdfPath As String
Set webBrowser2 = webControl.Object
pdfPath = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Internal Framework Summary.pdf"
webBrowser2.Navigate pdfPath
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Me.webControl.ControlSource = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Internal Framework Summary.pdf" 
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
loadPDFFile
End Sub
```

[image]

**Current Registry setting:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need a Registry setting:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

Try setting it to 0 (zero) to make the control to use the current browser emulation.

Source: [Everything You Never Wanted to Know About the Access WebBrowser Control](https://www.devhut.net/2019/10/18/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-the-access-webbrowser-control/)

and my comment of 2020-11-13.

> Bonus tip:
>
> After setting MSACCESS.EXE to your preferred value, do
> check the setting for OUTLOOK.EXE. Adjusting that will probably make
> most of your received e-mail newsletters render as intended.

To display the file, use this *ControlSource*:

```
="=" & [URL]
```

where URL is the field holding the full path to the file wrapped in octothorpes, for example:

```
#http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#
```

Comment: @Gustav That is a great link, However, I have changed the Registry settings to `0` but still getting the same error. I have also tried to change the line `Me.webBrowser1.ControlSource = pdfFileFullPath` to `Me.webControl.ControlSource = """ & pdfFileFullPath & """` but its still not working for me please see updated post.

Comment: See extended answer, please.

Comment: @Gustav thanks. All is working now, I have also notice that a `pdf` file name` `xyz.pdf` does not load until its renamed to just `xyz` in this case the extension become invisible. Therefore `Me.webControl.ControlSource = """ & pdfPath & """` works just fine! Thanks for your direction!